# Squid: bypass url_rewrite_program when request is https

Tags: rewrite, https, squid

I have a url rewriter working in squid currently. The problem is that, while it works fine for HTTP, HTTPS requests obviously don't work, even when rewritten with the same URL (because my server would essentially be doing a man-in-the-middle attack in that case).

So my question is, is there a rule to determine which requests are sent or not sent to the url_rewrite_program?

EDIT:
I tried the following, but https urls are still getting rewritten

```
#don't rewrite HTTPS                                                                                          
acl HTTPS_URLS url_regex -i ^https://.*$
url_rewrite_access deny HTTPS_URLS

url_rewrite_program /etc/squid3/rewrite.pl
```

Answer (score -2):

I resolve this case following code ;

```
acl p_http proto HTTP
url_rewrite_access allow p_http
url_rewrite_access deny all
url_rewrite_program /usr/bin/squidGuard
```

maybe useful for you.